# How to advertise in our own android apps?

Tags: android, ads

I have an app and at the end of app, I want to display advertisement...just like other apps showing the advertisment of olx and other sites or products.

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Payment... :P Well I went to admob site and when they ask for payment, I found that cross marks on the tab was looking so beautiful....

Comment: Aisa minus mat lao mere pass......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the offical android tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html